# broadcast receiver not getting called with alarm

Tags: android

I'm trying to call a broadcast receiver at a certain time by setting an alarm. It doesn't appear to be getting called at all. I'm trying to debug with logcat.

My set up for the alarm is something like this:

```
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar notifyAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();

    notifyAlarm.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
    notifyAlarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 2378530, intent, 0);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notifyAlarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

My receiver is as follows:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG ="test receiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Log.v(TAG, "receiver called");

}



    }
```

also in the manifest I have:

```
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
</application>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a `.` to the front of the name in the manifest like this `<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>`

Answer (score -1):

Thinking about it, I'm not sure you can send a broadcast to a `BroadcastReceiver` using an explicit `Intent` as you are doing it...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
```

Try giving the `<receiver` section an `<intent-filter>` example...

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mypackage.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then when you create your `Intent`, do it as follows...

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.mypackage.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING");
```

Comment: @user1763170 : OK, try changing the *flags* parameter of `getBroadcast(...)` from `0` to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: Eventually figured out what was wrong. The original code works but it was randomly deciding how many seconds to use as I hadn't specified it. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @user1763170 : Yeah, thinking about it I should have spotted that as a reason for it not being an exact timing.

Comment: I should also probably mention I changed Calendar.HOUR to Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY